# Why does \usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern} overwrite the math mode font?

Tags: newtxmath, lmodern

I'm working on some code and want to use `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}` for the typewriter font. For whatever reason, after importing the package, my math mode font resets back to computer modern rather than the desired, and requested, `newtxmath` font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{cmletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{cmletters}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{cmletters}{"15}
\begin{document}
$exp$
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `lmodern` package, I get the left image when using math mode, which is desired, but I get ugly typewriter font. If I uncomment that line, I get the CMU font in math mode, but a correct typewriter font. Does the `lmodern` package do something internally to reset the math mode font?

[image: Good math mode font but bad typewriter font]
[image: Bad math mode font but good typewriter font]

Comment: you could look into lmodern.sty to answer your question, it is not very long. You would perhaps even see an interesting option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point. I found the problem and will post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into `lmodern.sty` as suggested by Ulrike's comment.

The issue is that it redefines the symbol fonts for not just the typewriter font. I created `mylmodern.sty` to remove those alterations (following the GUST Font License):

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}

\DeclareOption{nomath}{\endinput}
\DeclareOption{variablett}{%
  \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmvtt}
}
\DeclareOption{lighttt}{%
  \let\lmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\endinput
```

Comment: I also hinted that there is suitable option. Simply load the style with the `nomath` option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps now I understand *what* options are for a package rather than blindly copying them!

Comment: Though, I still liked going into the .sty file since I want to use the roman sans-serif fonts; just not the serif fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load `lmodern`, but just issue the necessary commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% use Latin Modern Typewriter for tt
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
% but light
\makeatletter
\let\lmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$a+b$

\texttt{abc \textbf{abc}}

\end{document}
```

[image]